# Messaging issues!

Tags: php

I have a functioning messaging script.
What I am trying to do is allow 2 extra things.

One is a message me button.
Second is the reply feature.

When a user sends a message, they select them from the dropdown box.
So its like `<option value ="id">` and it displays the username.

When using a message me button, I assume I need to post the username and select it from the list.
When replying, again I post the username and it selects it from the list?

```
<form method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=new'>
    <input type='hidden' name='rfrom' value='<?php echo $row['username']; ?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='rsubject' value='Re: <?php echo $row['title']; ?>' />
    <input type='hidden' name='rmessage' value='Re: <<?php echo $row['message']; ?>>' />
    <input type='submit' name='reply' class="button" value='Reply' />
</form>
```

This is the reply code. As you can see, I pass the username through as `$_POST['rfrom']`

I came up with the following code to select the user from the list.

```
$fromname=(isset($_POST['rfrom'])) ? $_POST['rfrom'] : ''; //ought to validate $_POST
$selected=($u==$fromname) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
echo "<option value='$uid'>$u</option>";
```

This doesn't work and when I click Reply, I just get the first user on the list.

Also, could someone confirm if I could use the id to do this instead of the username?
It would be easier when using the button to send a new message from a user's profile.

Thankyou for reading, I hope you can help!

#### EDIT

I am now passing the user id through using `$_POST['rfrom']`.

The user id will be the option value.

Still, I cannot get the correct user to be selected in the list.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would most definitely use the userId in the POST of the form, and validate it as a INT on the far side, this will also keep names like Drop O'Tables from breaking your form.

Comment: I have used the user id and added selected as the above posted commented. Still not selecting the correct user however!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `$selected` when you're outputting the select box options.

Change:

```
echo "<option value='$uid'>$u</option>";
```

To:

```
echo "<option value='$uid' $selected>$u</option>";
```

Comment: I changed it so it was using the users id which is $uid usually. But when doing this (and even when was username) it is not selecting the correct username!

Answer (score 0):

There is a firefox bug in which it does not recognize `selected="selected"` properly when refreshing pages or using the browser back button. Test this in other browser to make sure it's your code that actually is the problem.

Copied verbatim from Mozillazine:

> Hold down the Shift key while pressing the Reload button.